# marking a card with 'check id'

Tags: debit-card, security

I read this [question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/66057/isnt-the-security-of-credit-cards-with-chip-worse-than-with-signature) . It was interesting to see this

"Before: If I lose the card, the finder needs to fake my signature (not too difficult, but not a freebie); if I mark the card with 'Check ID', there is a chance that he fails." - Aganju .

While Mr/Ms. Aganju talks/shares about credit card, could the same methodology be used for debit card as well ?

Also could somebody share about what is meant by 'Check ID' and how is it implemented/used ?

Lastly is 'check id' methodology only limited to US or is used world-over ?

Comment: Is [this question](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/26810/should-i-sign-the-back-of-my-credit-card) not a duplicate? In the US, card rules require a signature, the "check ID" is useless, it voids the card.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer that was for credit card and this is for debit card, but you are right, they are similar but only to the extent, the part where I asked about world-over scenario is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is that you are asking the sales clerk to demand a respectable photo ID, such as a driver's license, in addition to the signature (which they almost never look at).

However, the same sales clerks that don't try to confirm the signature also don't look at the card long enough to see this instruction. So realistically, while it's a good idea, it really doesn't work.

Comment: Plus world over things are slowly moving towards Chip+PIN systems there by making signature slightly redundant.

Comment: Meaning that now if you lose your card, there is _no_ chance at all for the finder/stealer to get caught. Physically _having_ the card is enough to use it all he wants. What a _security_ progress...

Comment: [I mean for the US, where PIN is not used]